# How to check maximum iOS version that given XCode version supports?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have XCode 13.2.1 and can't upgrade it because I'm using a 2013 Mac. My iPhone auto-updated to iOS 16.3.1 and now I can't run apps on this phone because it says `unsupported OS version`. Is there a place that lists the maximum iOS version that each version of XCode supports?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
2. Download support files for 16.3 (your iOS version) from https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/iOSDeviceSupport/16.3.zip and place it in the above path.
3. Restart Xcode.